# Angular : open sidenav with another component , ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

Tags: angular, sidenav

I can not open a sidenav from another component. The error is in the image at the end of this question. I would like to use this style of sidenav in my code:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/lronayrmlye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.ts

but I want to be able to open the sidenav from another component,

- Component containing the button: `navigation.component`
- Component containing the sidenav: `layouts.component`

#### `sidebar.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav, MatDrawer } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {

  public sideNavToggleSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  private drawer: MatDrawer;

  constructor() {}   

  setDrawer(drawer: MatDrawer) {
    this.drawer = drawer;
  }
  
  toggle(): void {
    this.drawer.toggle();
  }
}
```

#### `navigation.component.html`

```
 <mat-toolbar-row>
   <button type="button" class="open-sidebar" mat-button (click)="toggled()">
      Toggle sidenav
   </button>
 </mat-toolbar-row>
```

#### `navigation.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaMatcher } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { SidenavService } from '../services/sidenav.service';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationComponent  {

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) { }

  toggled() {
    this.sidenavService.toggle();
  }
}
```

#### `layouts.component.html`

```
<div>
  <div class="mat-typography">
    <app-navigation></app-navigation>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>

  <mat-drawer-container class="example-container colorred" autosize>
    <mat-drawer #drawer class="example-sidenav" position="end" mode="side">
      <p>Auto-resizing sidenav</p>
      <p *ngIf="showFiller">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      <button (click)="showFiller= !showFiller" mat-raised-button>
        Toggle extra text
      </button>
    </mat-drawer>
  </mat-drawer-container>
</div>
```

#### `layouts.component.ts`

```
import { Component, VERSION as ngv, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenavModule, MatDrawer } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { SidenavService } from 'src/app/layouts/services/sidenav.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layouts',
  templateUrl: './layouts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layouts.component.scss']
})
export class LayoutsComponent {

  @ViewChild('drawer') public drawer: MatDrawer;

  public showFiller = false;

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sidenavService.setDrawer(this.drawer);
  }
}
```

[image: error image]

Answer (score 3):

Everything is true in your code except you did not set static to the drawer in ViewChild in the layout component.

```
@ViewChild('drawer', { static: true }) public drawer: MatDrawer;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your service, you should update your `@Injectable` decorator like so:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

The error you are seeing basically says that the service is undefined in your component. In other words, it isn't being injected correctly. The above code is the easiest way to provide your service at the root (AppModule), so that it's available to be injected in your components.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response,  I did it and it doesn't change anything. The undefinite property is the one on : this.drawer.toggle();
Why doesn't it work?